# how to create an object or data structure of an abstract class in c++?

Tags: c++, class

Sir gave us a question in paper that was difficult for me to understand.
i need help to understand how this will be implemented.
Employees is an abstract class.
Define another class 'company' to hold a list of employees and a method to add employees in the list.

user should be able to create any number of employees.
i have tried to implement this but i got error that u cannot create an object of an abstract class.

this is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct dob
{
    int date,day,year;
};
class Employee
{
public:
    string Name;
    int ID;
    string Department;
    double MonthlyGrossSSalary;
    double MonthlyNetSalary;

    Employee (string,int,string,double,double);
    void CalculateAnnualIncomeTax();
    void CalculateMonthlyIncomeTax();
    virtual void print()=0;
};
class PermanentEmployee : protected Employee
{
public:
    double ProvidentFund;
    double AnnualMedicalInsuranceLimit;

    PermanentEmployee(double pf,double amil,string name,int id,string dep,double mgs,double mns):Employee(name,id,dep,mgs,mns)
    {
        ProvidentFund = pf;
        AnnualMedicalInsuranceLimit = amil;
    }
};
class ContractualEmployee : public Employee
{
public:
    dob ContractStartDate;
    dob ContractEndDate;

    ContractualEmployee(dob csd,dob ced,string name,int id,string dep,double mgs,double mns):Employee(name,id,dep,mgs,mns)
    {
        ContractStartDate = csd;
        ContractEndDate = ced;
    }
};
class Company
{
public:
    Employee *list;
    void AddEmployee();

};
void datainput(string &,int &,string &,double &,double &);
int main()
{
    char option;
    string name; string dep;
    int id; double mgs; double mns;
    PermanentEmployee PE;
    ContractualEmployee * CE;

    cout << "Select Type of Employee"<< endl;
    cout << "Permanent Employee     [P][p] "<<endl;
    cout << "Contractual Employee       [C][c] "<<endl;
    cout << "Enter Type of Employee"<< endl;
    cin >> option;

    switch(option)
    {
    case 'P': case 'p':
         datainput(name,id,dep,mgs,mns);

        break;
    case 'C': case 'c':
        break;

    }
    return 0;
} 
void datainput(string & n,int & no,string & d,double & mg,double & mn)
{
    cout << "Enter Data of Employee "<< endl;
    cout << "Enter name of Employee:";
    cin >> n;
    cout<<endl << "Enter ID of Employee: ";
    cin >> no;
    cout <<endl<< "Enter Department of Employee: ";
    cin >> d;
    cout <<endl<< "Enter Monthly Gross Salary of Employee: ";
    cin >> mg;
    cout <<endl<< "Enter Monthly Net Salary of Employee: ";
    cin >> mn;
}
```

Comment: Before you can make any objects of a class, all pure virtual functions must have an implementation (ie ContractualEmployee::print must be defined)

Comment: Perhaps `PermanentEmployee` and `ContractualEmployee` should override (implement) the abstract function?

Comment: NB - your compiler will have told you exactly which functions aren't implemented and in which classes.

Comment: okayy i got it thank u..

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question in topic: It is impossible to instantiate abstract class.
If you want to add any employee, you have to have a normal class that has all the methods defined. In your case you have to implement
PermanentEmployee::print()
and
ContractualEmployee::print()

Answer (score 0):

You can't create the `object` of the **abstract class** but you can create the **pointer** of the **abstract class** and you can do the stuff you want.

As `print()` is virtual function, you need to implement 
`PermanentEmployee::print()` and  `ContractualEmployee::prrint()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

> how to create an object ... of an abstract class in c++?

An object of an abstract class is created by writing a concrete class, which inherits the abstract class and creating an instance of that concrete class. A child of an abstract class is concrete if it overrides all pure virtual member functions.

> how to create a ... data structure of an abstract class in c++?

This is a bit trickier. Typically, data structures in C++ are homogeneous i.e. they only contain objects of same type. However, different derived classes of a same parent are still separate types and therefore cannot be stored in a homogeneous data structure as such.

Run time polymorphism can be achieved by indirection i.e. pointers and references. A pointer to base can point to the base sub objects of any class that derives from that base. Therefore you can have a data structure that contains pointers to instances of any derived class.

Example:

```
struct ConcreteEmployee1 : Employee
{
    ConcreteEmployee1() : Employee("", 0, "", 0, 0) {};
    void print(){};
};

struct ConcreteEmployee2 : Employee
{
    ConcreteEmployee2() : Employee("", 0, "", 0, 0) {};
    void print(){};
};


ConcreteEmployee1 e1;
ConcreteEmployee2 e2;
std::vector<Employee*> v;
v.push_back(&e1);
v.push_back(&e2);
```